# Circular Reference on entity relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

My database is code first and I'm stuck on a concept that's preventing me from moving forward with my development.

I have an N to N relationship in three models:

- TicTacToeTruth can have 1-to-N TicTacToeAction
- TicTacToeAction can have 1-to-N TicTacToeTruth
- TicTacToeActionTruths => associative model

```
builder.HasKey(bA => new { at.TicTacToeTruthId, at.TicTacToeActionId });

builder.HasOne<TicTacToeTruth>(b => b.TicTacToeTruth )
    .WithMany(b => b.TicTacToeActionTruths)
    .HasForeignKey(b => b.TicTacToeTruthId);

builder.HasOne<TicTacToeAction>(a => a.TicTacToeAction)
       .WithMany(a => a.TicTacToeActionTruths )
       .HasForeignKey(a => a.TicTacToeActionId);
```

The code for my get endpoint from the controller is as follows:

```
var TruthsWithActions = await _context.TicTacToeTruths
    .Include(bp => bp.TicTacToeActionTruths)
    .ThenInclude(bpa => bpa.TicTacToeAction)
    .ToListAsync();
```

When I run my code, it loops endlessly. By limiting the results, I'm sure it's building my json tree in a loop.

Do you have any idea how I could load the results without errors?  Thanks you in advance for your help !!

In SQL it would look like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[TicTacToeActionTruths] tr
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TicTacToeActions] act ON act.Id = tr.TicTacToeActionId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TicTacToeTruths] truth on truth.Id = tr.TicTacToeBodyPartId
```

I hope to be able to load data, and understand why I'm having this problem.

I've tried to ignore `ReferenceLoopHandling` so that looping values are excluded from serialization instead of throwing an exception.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
```

Limiting the depth of results with `.Take(3)`

Comment: For the best results, project out (`Select`) into a model what you want to convert into JSON rather than trying to serialize a recursively referencing entity graph. If you do want to serialize self-referencing structures then look at options like PreserveReferencesHandling in Newtonsoft to serialize references rather than endlessly creating nested instances.

Comment: @StevePy Hello, thanks for your advice on serialization. I take note of your comments. If I'm not mistaken, this won't solve my current problem, but it will optimize my object transformation.

Comment: I've added a solution based on your comments. Does this seem correct to you? @StevePy . Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified my request for a select as mentioned @StevePy
I'm not sure this is best practice, but it works.

Thank you all for your help. Don't hesitate to react if necessary.

```
var truths = await _context.TicTacToeTruths
            .Select(bp => new TicTacToeTruth
            {
                Id = bp.Id,
                Name = bp.Name,

                TicTacToeActions = bp.TicTacToeActions.Select(action => new TicTacToeAction
                {
                    Id = action.Id,
                    Name = action.Name
                }).ToList()
            })
            .ToListAsync();

        return truths;
```

Comment: Yep, though I recommend defining a separate view model/DTO class rather than a potentially partially filled entity class. I.e. TicTacToeTruthDto + TicTacToeActionDto. The main reason is to avoid confusion if you have methods that take a Truth etc. as to whether they receive an actual fully populated, tracked entity, or a partially filled projection which would have empty fields and/or relationships,

Answer (score 0):

If you want many to many, you don't need a mapping table unless you want to store extra information in it. And in this case, you don't need anything in the `FluentApi`

```
public class TicTacToeTruth
{
    public TicTacToeTruth()
    {
         //Not required, but it will prevent any null reference errors for this list
         this.TicTacToeActions = new HashSet<TicTacToeAction>();
    }

    public int Id  { get; set; } 
    ....
    public ICollection<TicTacToeAction> TicTacToeActions { get; set; }
}

public class TicTacToeAction
{
    public TicTacToeAction()
    {
         //Not required, but it will prevent any null reference errors for this list
         this.TicTacToeTruths = new HashSet<TicTacToeTruth>();
    }

    public int Id  { get; set; } 
    ....
    public ICollection<TicTacToeTruth> TicTacToeTruths { get; set; }
}
```

That's enough to make the relationship many-to-many with migration.

Query example

```
var truths = await context.TicTacToeTruths.Include(x => x.TicTacToeActions).ToListAsync();

var actions = await context.TicTacToeActions.Include(x => x.TicTacToeTruths).ToListAsync();
```

Adding example

````
var truth = await context.TicTacToeTruths.Include(x => x.TicTacToeActions).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == 1)

//dont need here to add ```action``` in the database
var action = new TicTacToeAction{ ...... };
truth.TicTacToeActions.Add(action)

//save here will update ```truth``` and will add ```action``` in database
await  context.SaveChangesAsync();
````

Making a connection between existing records

```
var action = await context.TicTacToeActions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == 1);

var truth = await context.TicTacToeTruths.Include(x => x.TicTacToeActions).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == 1)

truth.TicTacToeActions.Add(action)

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your help. I wouldn't have the problem if my relationship was 1-to-1. However, TicTacToeTruth must be able to be linked to several TicTacToeActions (many-to-many) and TicTacToeAction must be able to be linked to several TicTacToeTruths (many-to-many), which explains the reason for my table mapping. 

Indeed, I chose to have a Many-to-many with class for join entity relationship rather than a Many-to-many with named join table (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many)

Would my many-to-many understanding be wrong ? Thank you !

Comment: For many-to-many you still don't need mapping table, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have implemented according to your recommendation. We're making progress and I'm getting results!


However, I get a tree with recusive level (Truth => Action => Truth => Action). I'd like to obtain a single-level result tree, without recursive link. How do you suggest I proceed ?

Don't hesitate to ask me for details, as comments are limited in their formatting.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have any recusive when load data , You loads related entities as part of the query only when you use ```Include()``` method which include onle the first layer of releted entity and go deeper into with ```ThenInclude()``` method

Comment: You can have recusive loading if you use ```AutoInclide()``` method in your  ```OnModelCreating```